# How to use Scanner's delimiter method

Tags: java, file-io, hashmap, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am currently working on an implementation of the game Risk. In my Board class which constructs the countries, continents, and their adjacencies, I am reading in three different text files. When I construct a new continent, its' constructor expects the following
(String name, int bonusArmies , ArrayList memberCountries).
Now, I am using a Scanner to read from a text file that is organized as so,
The name, bonus army that it has, and the rest on each line is its member countries.

North America,5,Alaska,Alberta,Central America,Eastern United States,Greenland,Northwest Territory,Ontario,Quebec,Western United States
South America,2,Argentina,Brazil,Venezuela
Europe,5,Great Britain,Iceland,Northern Europe,Scandinavia,Southern Europe,Ukraine,Western Europe
Africa,3,Congo,East Africa,Egypt,Madagascar,North Africa,South Africa
Asia,7,Afghanistan,China,India,Irkutsk,Japan,Kamchatka,Middle East,Mongolia,Siam,Siberia,Ural,Yakutsk
Australia,2,Eastern Australia,Indonesia,LotR,New Guinea,Western Australia

I know I need to set a delimiter for Scanner which I have tried multiple approaches but, to no avail.Here is an example of what I tried for creating the Continents hashmap.

```
public void createContinents()
{   

    Scanner inputTwo = new Scanner( new File( "continents.txt");

while( inputTwo.hasNext())  //continues to create and add countries until their are none next
{   
    String line = inputTwo.nextLine();  //stores the entire line
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner( line);  //passes the entire line into Scanner
    lineScan.useDelimiter(","); //sets the Scanner's delimiter pattern

    String name = inputTwo.next();  //stores the first String which is the name of the current continent being created
    System.out.println( " the name is" + name);

    int bonusArmies = inputTwo.nextInt();   //stores the second String which is casted into an int for the continent bonus armies
    System.out.println(" the number of bonus armies is" + bonusArmies);

    ArrayList<Country> memberCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();  //creates an arraylist to hold the member countries of current continent

    while( inputTwo.hasNext())  //goes through the rest of the line to add the member countries until it reaches the end of the line
    {   

        memberCountries.add( countries.get(inputTwo.next()));//gets string name of country and pass it as key to store into temp arraylist of countries         
        System.out.println( "the member countries" + memberCountries);
    }

        continent = new Continent( name,  bonusArmies,  memberCountries);   //creates continent
        continents.put(name , continent);   //associates a key to the current continent

}


    inputTwo.close();

 }
```

[image: Here is a picture of the error I get when test running it]

This is the text that is in that image.

```
    PS C:\Users\repti_000\desktop\risk\homeworks2120\game> java BoardTester
     the name is
    SouthAmerica,2,Argentina,Brazil,Venezuela 

    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Board.createContinents(Board.java:66)
    at Board.loadBoard(Board.java:141)
    at Board.<init>(Board.java:27)
    at BoardTester.main(BoardTester.java:7)
   PS C:\Users\repti_000\desktop\risk\homeworks2120\game>
```

Comment: Please describe actual behavior and why it is undesirable.

Comment: You forgot to close the `new Scanner();`. 
Make it:
`Scanner inputTwo = new Scanner( new File( "continents.txt"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed the scanners and some variables to be clearer and added a few comments with CHANGED to it. I wonder why your hashmap continents looks like continents(name, continent) whilst your store the name of a continent (as you give it with the constructor). Using continent.getName() seems like a better practice.

As pointed out by Sir RotN, you used the wrong scanner and your names were unclear indeed. Try to keep your variable names a bit clearer, it should help time.

```
    public void createContinents()  { 

    //  Scan the continents.txt file
    Scanner worldScan = new Scanner( new File( "continents.txt");

    //  While worldScan has a next line, run loop
    //  CHANGED: not hasNext(), but hasNextLine()
    while( worldScan.hasNextLine()) {

        //  Create a scanner for the selected line in worldScan
        String continentLine = inputTwo.nextLine();
        Scanner continentScan = new Scanner(continentLine);
        continentScan.useDelimiter(",");

        //  Grab the continent from the scanner
        String name = continentScan.next();
        System.out.println( " the continent name is" + name);

        //  Grab the armies from the scanner
        //  CHANGED: you read it out as a string, not as an int
        int bonusArmies = Integer.toString(continentScan.next());
        System.out.println(" the number of bonus armies is" + bonusArmies);

        //  Instantiate loop variable countries
        ArrayList<Country> memberCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();

        while( continentScan.hasNext()) {
            memberCountries.add(countries.get(continentScan.next()));
            System.out.println( "the member countries" + memberCountries);
        }

        //  Instantiate loop variable continent
        Continent continent = new Continent( name,  bonusArmies,  memberCountries);

        //  Add continent to the hashmap
        continents.put(name,continent);

        continentScan.close();
    }

    worldScan.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the data from inputTwo instead of lineScan. You should consider clearer names here, that makes it simpler to detect this kind of problems. Instead of inputTwo mapData or worldScanner and instead of lineScan maybe continentData.